# How to convert and filter JSON data using Typescript Angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, filter

I have string as below

```
configValues="{listValues:[{name:chennai,attrs:[{id:1,name:kumar},{id:2,name:john}]},{name:bengalur,attrs:[{id:1,name:raj},{id:2,name:nick}]}]}"
```

which holds list of values based on city. How can I convert it to a JSON object and filter based on name?

I have used below method but it throws filter of undefined

```
 var inputString=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('configValues'));
 var outputString= inputString.listValues.filter(val=> val.name ==='chennai')
```

Could someone please help me to convert to json and filter using typescript ?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('configValues'))` -> don't do `stringify` here or pass a string, just `JSON.parse(configValues)` EDIT: also, I just noticed that your JSON isn't properly formatted. It needs double quotes `"` around keys and strng values. Make sure your data is in the correct format, as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(configValues); // <-- see this line
var outputString= myJson.listValues.filter(val=> val.name ==='chennai')
```

Comment: Also, the JSON doesn't have quotes around keys/string values.

Comment: @VLAZ configValues = "{'listValues':[{'name':'chennai','attrs':[{'id':'1','name':'kumar'},{'id':'2','name':'john'}]},{'name':'bengalur','attrs':[{'id':'1','name':'raj'},{'id':'2','name':'nick'}]}]}"

var inputString=JSON.parse(configValues);

getting error  as Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: @Nishanth the keys and string values need to be in double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`.